# Draggable markers on Google transit map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a transit map (with bus/metro indications) using Google Maps, but when I create the "start" and "end" markers from inputs (with autocomplete addresses), there's no way to drag any marker despite set `drag` option as `true`.

Changing the `travelMode` option to `google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING` the draggin' is enabled. And going back this property to `google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT` the daggin' goes back to disabled.

There's a way to solve this issue?

**Code:**

```
  var directionsService;
  var directionsDisplay;

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {lat: -32.89, lng: -68.845}  // Mendoza.
    });

    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      draggable: true,
      map: map,
      panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
    });

    directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
      var addresses = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs[0];
      document.getElementById('from').value = addresses.start_address;
      document.getElementById('to').value = addresses.end_address;
    });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('go'), 'click', displayRoute);

    var input_from = document.getElementById('from');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_from);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var input_to = document.getElementById('to');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_to);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    displayRoute();
  }

  function displayRoute() {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('from').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('to').value,
      //travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        console.log(response);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }      

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Comment: How are you adding the markers? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I added the used code to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: So the markers are the default DirectionsRenderer Markers?  I could see why google might not make those draggable, you might need to add your own draggable Markers with dragend listeners to recompute the directions when they  move.

Comment: @geocodezip the markers would be DirectionRenderer Markers, changing the `travelMode` to `google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING` (commented code line) the markers can be moved... I don't understand why when is in `TRANSIT` the markers are undraggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" (hack) I found, using trial and error, is to prevent to show the markers the API creates:

```
var directionsDisplay = new m.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true, // Supressing the default markers
    map: map,

    // another options...

});
```

And implement my own function to show markers:

```
function placeMarker(e, t) {
    t < 2 && (markers[t] = new m.Marker({
        position: e,
        draggable: true,  // YES! It's draggable!
        map: map
    }), m.event.addListener(markers[t], "dragend", function() {
        geocodePosition(markers[t].getPosition(), t);
    }), markers[t].setVisible(true), geocodePosition(markers[t].getPosition(), t), arrangeBounds());
}
```

Then, the markers are draggable using a Google transit map... The solution is late but, I hope, not least.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "draggable" mode is not permited to the TRANSIT travel mode. Just now I'm trying to find a way and I found your question by the way.

**EDIT**

As the google documentation says:

> Users may modify cycling, walking or driving directions displayed
>   using a DirectionsRenderer dynamically if they are draggable, allowing
>   a user to select and alter routes by clicking and dragging the
>   resulting paths on the map. You indicate whether a renderer's display
>   allows draggable directions by setting its draggable property to true.
>   **Transit directions cannot be made draggable.**

Check it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitOptions

We will have to find another way... if I find it I'll make you know, if you find it first I'll be grateful if you told me.